# How to manage unity script in a more efficient way?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

Currently I am developing my own Unity project. While my project become bigger, I started to realize how horrible it would be to allow each component having their own life cycle.

For example, I don't know if a component needs to fetch for another component that only initial in `Start` method, whereas this component raises up this call in `Awake` method. It would be a nightmare.

So I created an interface called IController, and having all the controlling components inherent from it with overriding parent method. Then I manage them in a central controller. It looks like this:

```
Public class CentralController{
    Public NPCController npcController;
    Public MusicController musicController;
    Public CharacterController characterController;

    Public List<IController> controllers;
    Public void Awake(){
           if (npcController != null)
               controllers.Add(npcController);
           if (musicController !=null)
               controllers.Add(musicController);
           if (characterController != null)
               controllers.Add(characterController);

    }
    Public void Update(){
        foreach (IController controller in controllers)
           {
               controller.Update();
           }
    }
}
```

I add a reference for each controller because I want to assign them through the inspector. However it seems a little stupid because I need to change the awake method every time I add a new controller to the system, at the same time violating open close principal.

What should I do to make the script scalable?

Comment: never fetch another component every update... why not have a list of controllers and just have the awake make sure every element is assigned?

Comment: I am trying to prevent me from stupid fetching descision and thats why I make this centrol controllers. I aslo agree we should make sure the elements are all assigned in Awake method but my problem is that if method exist to add more controller s without modifying the head controller itself

Comment: You could make the controller register with the head controller as part of the base code.....

Comment: Any example pls = =

Comment: if the list of controllers in your central controller class is private static, and has static methods to register, and all your controllers are built from a base class, as part of the base contstructor it can call centralcontroller.register(this) and add itself.... therefore there are no unregistered controllers

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, however all my controller are set in the inspector and how should the constructor be able to work properly?

Comment: it would work the same you can then drop as many controllers on objects in scenes and they would all register

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a single, specific answer to your question because there is no simple work-around for such cases. This is one of those situations which should be project-specific and thought thoroughly before even coding stage begins. 
With a little patience, everyone can come up with robust frameworks if they just pause a little and don't be afraid of stepping back and do nothing (code-wise) which will pay for itself, 100% sure.
Unity projects, just like any other bare-bone projects, should be built based on a framework that you've designed meticulously, everything laid out perfectly and only then start using unity scripting libraries. Sometimes (especially for big projects) you should start with the C#, architecture the framework and then connect it with Unity engine carefully, cause lots of unity methods like Update, Start and Awake are dangerous places that performance can be ruined and managing them becomes cumbersome. (They've built for ease of use.)

In my opinion, if you want to think component-wise (traditional unity programming style) and build a big game, it's going to be a big mess anyways.

I have two suggestions, first, try to build a framework ground up in which everything's in the place and wellthought (which requires knowledge around software engineering and software architecture), or if you don't want to do that, start learning the DOTS, the modern unity programming language style which is not object oriented, but rather data oriented and comes with default performance and clean-code style right at the get go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am starting to read the Unity Document about DOTS

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your pain, I have been there.
To keep your code maintainable and reusable I recommend you to follow SOLID principles:
S - Single Responsibility, a class should have only single system to worry about.
O - Open/Close principle, every class should be open for extension and close for modification, which means using inheritance and polymorphism for specific form of behaviour of a class.
L - Liskov's substituting principle, which guides us when to use and when not to use inheritance.
I - Interface segregation.
D - Dependency inversion, which means to use abstractions for dependencies.
Below is the link for a great Unity talk on SOLID:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIf3-aDTOOA

Apart from that you need to keep your systems loosely coupled for reusability, for that you can use Observer pattern(using Actions or events and delegates).

Creating an architecture in compliance with SOLID does take efforts during initial stage of projects but this effort does pay off as your project grows bigger.

I wouldn't recommend you to go straight up and start using DOTS. DOTS is not meant for every project it is something where you need to accomplish various tasks simultaneously and hence need to vectorise your code accordingly.

Comment: In fact I already heard about SOLID when I learnt Software Engineering, but still given is a great study material. Thanks bro. BTW Could you give some example on using delegates for the CentralController Script's Sake?